# How to reorder 4 divs with drag and drop (using angular2/4)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, drag-and-drop

Assuming I have 4 divs width and height of 100px with a "float left" within a parent div that is a wide rectangle. Is there some elegant way to make it so that I can drag and drop the divs to reorder them on that wide horizontal bar?

Comment: Is using `float` a requirement?

Comment: Currently I am using that to align the divs on the page so they are right next to each other horizontally. Not sure how else I could do it. If there is some other way to make it so that it doesnt use float and looks the same, I am open to the possibility.

Comment: I think you can use `flex-box` and DOM manipulation to achieve this. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.. Use javascript to calculate what index the dragged element should be dropped at and then `flex-box` should handle the rest. I don't have time right now to provide a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Found an example w/ jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: ".portlet-header",
    cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
    placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
  });

  $(".portlet")
    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
    .find(".portlet-header")
    .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

  $(".portlet-toggle").on("click", function() {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.portlet {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 0.1em;
}

.portlet-header {
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.portlet-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.portlet-content {
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.portlet-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-header">Feed</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">My Feed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">My News</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-header">Shop</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">My Shopping</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">My Links </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```